# how to count children in object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json array ..I want to refactor the json object ..but I am not able to make as expected output .I want to search all item or object  and insert the children  of parent ..I try like that

https://jsfiddle.net/nk6v0y36/1/

```
var new_Arry = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    var childeren = [];
    obj.con_id = arry[i].con_id;
    obj.children = [{
        con_to: arry[i].con_to
    }];
    new_Arry.push(obj)
}

console.log(new_Arry)
```

Expected output:

```
[{
    "con_id": 11,
    "children": [{
        "con_to": 12
    }]
}, {
    "con_id": 12,
    "children": [{
        "con_to": 13
    }, {
        "con_to": 14
    }]
}, {
    "con_id": 13,
    "children": []
}, {
    "con_id": 14,
    "children": [{
        "con_to": 15
    }]
}, {
    "con_id": 15,
    "children": [{
        "con_to": 16
    }]
}, {
    "con_id": 16,
    "children": []
}]
```

After answer

https://jsfiddle.net/nk6v0y36/7/

Answer not working..

Comment: you're not checking if the ID exists already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As thisOneGuy said, you are not checking if a con_id already exists in the new array, so for each element in the old array you are creating a corresponding new one.  Your expected output though shows you want to merge these multiple con_id values into a single object.

You are also creating objects with con_to properties in the children arrays even when there is no such property, which again your expected output suggests you do not way.

One way to fix this would be:

```
var new_Arry = [];
var new_Hash = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
    if (new_Hash[arry[i].con_id] === undefined ) {
        var obj = {
            con_id: arry[i].con_id,
            children: []
        };
        if( arry[i].con_to !== undefined ) {
            obj.children.push({ con_to: arry[i].con_to });
        }
        new_Hash[obj.con_id] = new_Arry.push(obj) - 1;
    } else if( arry[i].con_to !== undefined ) {
       new_Arry[new_Hash[arry[i].con_id]].children.push({ con_to: arry[i].con_to });
    }
}

console.log(new_Arry);
```

The key here is the new_Hash array, which uses the con_id value as its key, and stores the respective index in the new_Arry as its value.

So for each con_id in arry it first checks the new_Hash to see if there is an entry for it.  If not then there is no entry in new_Arry, so it creates a new one.

Firstly the basic object, with con_id and a children array is created.  It then checks whether there is a con_to property in arry, and only if there is does it add one as an object to the children array.

This object is then added to new_Arry and new_Hash updated so that an element for con_id references the new new_Arry index.  As the `.push()` method returns extends an array and returns the new array length, the new index will always be this value minus one.

However if an entry for con_id was found in new_Hash then all you need to do it add the con_to value to the existing children array.  Whilst presumably if there are multiple con_id entries in arry they must contain a con_to value, it also checks this just to be safe.  The index number for the new_Arry as returned by `new_Hash[arry[i].cond_id]`.

Incidentally, the reason for explicitly checking for `undefined` rather than seeing if value equates to true or false to check for its existence is a con_id or con_to value of 0 would be treated as false and skipped.

Comment: Sorry, there were a couple of types using cond_id instead of con_id, and the first if statement was a not if but supposed to be an if.  I have updated the code in the answer and here it is in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lq5u99c7/

Answer (score 0):

Like this -

```
var new_Arry = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {    
  var obj = {};
  var childeren = [];
  obj.con_id = arry[i].con_id;
  var child = [];
  var childrenObj = {};
  childrenObj.con_to = arry[i].con_to;
  child.push(childrenObj);
  obj.children = child;
  new_Arry.push(obj)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nk6v0y36/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct answer with the correct output : https://jsfiddle.net/nk6v0y36/4/

Basically you need to loop through your array to check if the con_id exists in that array, if it does, just add to children, if it doesnt add a new object.

```
var new_Arry = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
  var obj = {};
  var childeren = [];
  if (new_Arry.length > 0) {
    console.log('start')
    console.log(new_Arry.length);

    var thisBool = false;
    for (var j = 0; j <= new_Arry.length; j++) {
      console.log('inside')
      if (new_Arry[j]) {
        if (new_Arry[j].con_id === arry[i].con_id) {
          console.log('has children')
          new_Arry[j].children[new_Arry[j].children.length] = {
            con_to: arry[i].con_to
          }
        } else {
        thisBool = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if(thisBool){
    obj.con_id = arry[i].con_id;
    obj.children = [{
      con_to: arry[i].con_to
    }];
    new_Arry.push(obj)
    }
  } else {
    console.log('no children')
    obj.con_id = arry[i].con_id;
    obj.children = [{
      con_to: arry[i].con_to
    }];
    new_Arry.push(obj)
  }
}
```

Check the output in the console log to see it's correct :)